# Finding the max value in a python loop

Tags: python

I have a list of data that I'm trying to find the max value from with python. My current code will loop over the data and render all possible combinations of the data, however I can't figure out how to render the max from the results.

Below is my current setup:

```
street = %sql SELECT * FROM streets

 for i in range(len(flight)):
    for j in range(len(flight)):
        for k in range(len(flight)):
            A = flight[i][2]
            B = flight[k][2]
            num = flight[i][4] , flight[j][4] , flight[k][4]
            numsum = sum(num)
            print A, B, numsum
```

Printing `flight` will render the below

```
+----+-----------+----------------------+----------------------+---+
| id |   flight  |        Start         |          End         |dis|
+----+-----------+----------------------+----------------------+---+
| 0  |     w     |       SFO            |          DEN         | 4 |
| 1  |     e     |       DEN            |          NYC         | 7 |
| 1  |     e     |       DEN            |          ORD         | 7 |
```

However the max with throw the below error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-283-770cd29ebd83> in <module>()
      8             num = street[i][4] , street[j][4] , street[k][4]
      9             numsum = sum(num)
---> 10             print A, B, max(numsum)
     11 

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

If I remove the max from the last line everything in the database will print. For example:

```
SFO ORD 35
DEN JFK 12
SFO JFK 94
LAX DEN 54
...
```

Can someone help me figure out how to get the max value in numsum so the result prints like this:

```
 SFO JFK 94
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your error does not match up with the code you listed. Please show the **exact** code you are running.

Comment: What does `numsum` look like? Can you post a piece of code that defines an example?

Comment: could you provide an example input and the expected output!

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm still a python noob so any help is greatly appreciated :) I just updated the question to hopefully make it a bit more clear. Please let me know if there is any other information that could help.

Comment: I checked your updated code, which does INDEED help quite a bit. The thing is that what you're trying to do doesn't really match what your code is accomplishing. I'm assuming you're trying to find the longest distance (column 5) you can travel in three flights, but you don't actually make sure those connecting flights land and depart from the same destinations. For instance your final solution could be PDX -> SFO, HOU -> DEN, JFK -> NYC. They're just nonsensical data points.

Comment: Separately, it occurs to me that you can probably do all of this in your SQL query (which will be orders of magnitude faster than trying to do data manipulation in Python afterwards).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing what you're trying to do. Your algorithm isn't well thought-out. look at it this way:

```
for each_item in whatever_iterator:
    a = each_item[some_element]
    b = each_item[another_element]
    num = some, other, numbers
    sumnum = sum(num)  # hey that was easy!
    print a, b, sumnum  # every time through, let's print it!
```

Nowhere does this find the LARGEST. In order to do that, you'd want to iterate through and save `current_max = max(current_max, new_value)`

Looks like what you're looking to do is:

```
max_sumnum = (0, 0, 0)
for i, j, k in itertools.product(len(x), repeat=3):
    num = x[i][4], x[j][4], x[???][1][k][4]
    cur_sumnum = x[i][2], x[k][2], sum(num)
    max_sumnum = max(max_numsum, cur_sumnum, key=lambda tup: tup[2])
print max_sumnum
```

I use `itertools.product` here because it's a great shortcut for nested for loops.

```
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(5):
        for k in range(100):
            for m in range(2):
                foo(i, j, k, m)

# equivalent to....
for i, j, k, m in itertools.product(range(3), range(5),
                                    range(100), range(2)):
```

And I use the `repeat` keyword since you're doing a bunch of the same loops.

```
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        for k in range(3):

# equivalent to....
for i, j, k in itertools.product(range(3), repeat=3):
```